# Detect when Mobile Safari / Android Browser Navigation Bar Retracts via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, viewport

I'm trying to create a div that fills the entire viewport's width and height on a mobile device.  The problem is, Mobile Safari and Android Browser have a navigation menu that disappears once the user begins interacting with the page.  The navigation bar makes the viewport height smaller, but when it goes away, I can find no javascript event that I can listen to so I can get updated values for the viewport height and width.

Is there a JavaScript event that is fired when Mobile Safari's navigation menu retracts from view?  I was hoping there was an event I could listen to instead of firing a timer every x milliseconds to check the viewport height.

Here is a chart that explains the terminology when I say "navigation bar"

[image: Chart that defines the terminology for parts of the screen]

Answer (score -1):

Since the visible area is changed `window.onresize` should fire. Try:

```
window.onresize = function(event) { /* your stuff */ };
```